# Using an interger Arraylist to extract words from a string

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

how can I use the extract arraylist to get the words at that index in the text string?

```
ArrayList<Interger> extract = new ArrayList<Interger>();

extract.add(22); extract.add(37);

String text ="How do I get the this word? And this word?";
```

Result shoud be (word,word)

Comment: your question does not make sense to me.

Comment: Interger? that doesn't make sense (as @ScaryWombat notes), nor does the question. If you need serious help, please ask a *serious* question, one without sloppy code, one with real code, one that tells the details of your problem.

Comment: Plus you've gotten several replies to your previous question, replies that you've not responded to, nor have you up-voted any or accepted any. Why help if you're just going to ignore all previous help?

Comment: I got the question..w is a index 22 in the string text. OP wants to extract the word at index 22 and add it to the list. ArrayList is not meant to do such tasks you have to write code for this.

Comment: @Pramod so you think it means *how do I extract all words beginning with w* ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Words starting at index 22 and 37 in the string. Not all words starting with w. For e.g. extract.add(22) should add the word at index 22 to the list.

Comment: How hard is it make use `String#substring`?  This would allow you to get the all the characters starting at the given index, then you could walk till you found the current delimiter (ie space) to find the ending index

Comment: I would love to up vote answers by my rep is low. But I'm greatful for people who understand what I'm trying to do. thank you shmosel and Elliott Frisch.

Comment: You can [accept a correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the checkbox to the left of it.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
for (int index : extract) {
    words.add(text.substring(index).split("\\b")[0]);
}
System.out.println(words);
// [word, word]
```